# Inverse Mellin transform of products of gamma functions

Tags: contour-integration, gamma-function, mellin-transform

I want to calculate the inverse Mellin transform  of products  of 3 gamma functions.
$$F\left ( s \right )=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int \Gamma(s)\Gamma (2s+a)\Gamma( 2s+b)x^{-s}ds$$
Above contour integral has 3 poles.
$$s_{1}=-n$$
$$s_{2}=-\left ( \frac{n+a}{2} \right )$$
$$s_{3}=-\left ( \frac{n+b}{2} \right )$$
Which pole is used in contour integral?
$$F\left ( s \right )=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}}{n!}\Gamma \left ( a-2n \right )\Gamma \left ( -2n+b \right )x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left ( -1 \right )^{n}}{n!}\Gamma \left ( -\frac{n}{2}-\frac{a}{2} \right)\Gamma \left ( -n-a+b\right )x^{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{a}{2}}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\Gamma \left (-\frac{n}{2}-\frac{b}{2} \right )\Gamma (-n-b+a)x^{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{b}{2}}$$
Is this correct??

Comment: It is the integrand that has poles and not the "relation", and there are infinitely many of them as they depend on $n\in \mathbb N$. You may take the path of integration to be a vertical line that is to the right from all the poles of the integrand.

Comment: The residue theorem will work without problem, shifting the line of integration to the left

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Can you just ask if I shifting the line of integration to the left includes the poles?

Comment: Please look at answer of my question.  Thanks

Comment: Do you answer me?